# Cannot figure out Python3 syntax error with ftplib package

Tags: python-3.x, macos, terminal

I have a custom code for wifi router update, all required packages are installed and after running the code I have a syntax error

```
    User ~ % python3 main/main.py
  File "main/main.py", line 92
    ftp.retrbinary(f'RETR /tmp/backup.bin.gz', file.write)
                                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

And I cannot figure out what is not correct here.

The part with the "error" code is the following:

```
import ftplib


ftp=ftplib.FTP(router_ip_address)
with open('data/backup.bin.gz', 'wb') as file:
    ftp.retrbinary(f'RETR /tmp/backup.bin.gz', file.write)
tn.write(b"rm /tmp/backup.bin.gz\n")
tn.read_until(b"root@XiaoQiang:~#")
print('Backup is done!')
```

Comment: Just a guess, but I would say your syntax error results from the f before the ' in the line try ```ftp.retrbinary('RETR /tmp/backup.bin.gz', file.write)```

Comment: Thanks itprorh66! It worked. It seems "f" is unnecessary now, and the last time I saw the author the code was working as he said.

Comment: If your question has been answered, please indicate the fact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to itprorh66! It seems "f" is unnecessary now, and the last time I saw the author the code was working as he said.

The solution is `ftp.retrbinary('RETR /tmp/backup.bin.gz', file.write)` without "f" before 'RETR